# Add a new column and group attributes

Tags: r

I want to add a new column in R which summarizes my subgroups into groups.

Here my example:

```
id = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6)
subgroup = c("lightred","marine","cyan","rose","bordeaux","darkred","sky","gras","bottle","lightgreen","darkred","marine","lightgreen")
data = data.frame(cbind(id,subgroup))

> data
   id   subgroup
1   1   lightred
2   2     marine
3   2       cyan
4   3       rose
5   4   bordeaux
6   4    darkred
7   4        sky
8   5       gras
9   5     bottle
10  5 lightgreen
11  6    darkred
12  6     marine
13  6 lightgreen
```

Now I want to add a new column "colour" which groups the attributes into 3 gropus "red", "green" and "blue".
Can I assign the subgroups to a variable first and then assign them to a group?

```
red = "lightred", "darkred" , "rose" , "bordeaux"
blue = "marine", "cyan", "sky"
green = "gras", "bottle" , "lightgreen"
```

It should look like this at the end:

```
> data
   id   subgroup colour
1   1   lightred    red
2   2     marine   blue
3   2       cyan   blue
4   3       rose    red
5   4   bordeaux    red
6   4    darkred    red
7   4        sky   blue
8   5       gras  green
9   5     bottle  green
10  5 lightgreen  green
11  6    darkred    red
12  6     marine   blue
13  6 lightgreen  green
```

Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547597/dictionary-style-replace-multiple-items. Although, it would require a bit of modification.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51164948/add-a-new-column-based-on-grouping-attributes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `case_when` from `dplyr`:

```
red <- c("lightred", "darkred", "rose", "bordeaux")
blue <- c("marine", "cyan", "sky")
green <- c("gras", "bottle", "lightgreen")

data$colour <-
case_when(
    data$subgroup %in% red ~ "red",
    data$subgroup %in% blue ~ "blue",
    data$subgroup %in% green ~ "green",
    TRUE ~ data$subgroup
)
```

Answer (score 2):

A little unconventional approach with `cut`. We create a `list` of key-value pairs and then `match` those values with `data$subgroup`. We create `break` values as cumulative sum of `length` of each list and `labels` as `names` of the list.

```
new_list <- list('red' = c("lightred", "darkred" , "rose" , "bordeaux"),
                 'blue' = c("marine", "cyan", "sky"),
                  'green' = c("gras", "bottle" , "lightgreen"))


data$colour <- cut(match(data$subgroup, unlist(new_list)), 
               breaks = c(0,cumsum(lengths(new_list))), 
               labels = names(new_list))


data
#   id   subgroup colour
#1   1   lightred    red
#2   2     marine   blue
#3   2       cyan   blue
#4   3       rose    red
#5   4   bordeaux    red
#6   4    darkred    red
#7   4        sky   blue
#8   5       gras  green
#9   5     bottle  green
#10  5 lightgreen  green
#11  6    darkred    red
#12  6     marine   blue
#13  6 lightgreen  green
```

where

```
cumsum(lengths(new_list))
# red  blue green 
#   4     7    10
```

---

Another alternative (suggested by @Jaap) is we create a dataframe from the `new_list` using `stack` with `values` as individual colors and `ind` as corresponding group. Then we just `match`, `subgroup` with `values` and get the respective group (`ind`).

```
ref <- stack(new_list)
data$colour <- ref$ind[match(data$subgroup, ref$values)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
id = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6)
subgroup = c("lightred","marine","cyan","rose","bordeaux","darkred","sky","gras","bottle","lightgreen","darkred","marine","lightgreen")
data = data.frame(cbind(id,subgroup))

library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    colour = dplyr::case_when(
      grepl("(lightred)|(darkred)|(rose)|(bordeaux)", subgroup, perl = TRUE) ~ "red",
      grepl("(marine)|(cyan)|(sky)", subgroup, perl = TRUE) ~ "blue",
      grepl("(gras)|(bottle)|(lightgreen)", subgroup, perl = TRUE) ~ "green",
      TRUE ~ "else"
    )
  )
data
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `plyr`:

`mapvalues` from `x` to `y`. Here `x` represents the unique `subgroup` and `y` their corresponding `color` value to be mapped:

```
x = c("lightred", "darkred" , "rose" , "bordeaux", "marine", "cyan", "sky", "gras", "bottle" , "lightgreen" )
y = c(rep("red",4), rep("blue", 3), rep("green",3))

data %>% dplyr::mutate(color = plyr::mapvalues(subgroup, x,y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data$colour <-  ifelse(data$subgroup %in% red, "red", ifelse(data$subgroup %in% blue, "blue", "green"))

   id   subgroup colour
1   1   lightred    red
2   2     marine   blue
3   2       cyan   blue
4   3       rose    red
5   4   bordeaux    red
6   4    darkred    red
7   4        sky   blue
8   5       gras  green
9   5     bottle  green
10  5 lightgreen  green
11  6    darkred    red
12  6     marine   blue
13  6 lightgreen  green
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(a=merge(data,stack(list(red=red,blue=blue,green=green)),by.x="subgroup",by.y="values"))
     subgroup id   ind
1    bordeaux  4   red
2      bottle  5 green
3        cyan  2  blue
4     darkred  4   red
5     darkred  6   red
6        gras  5 green
7  lightgreen  5 green
8  lightgreen  6 green
9    lightred  1   red
10     marine  2  blue
11     marine  6  blue
12       rose  3   red
13        sky  4  blue

a[order(a$id),]

    subgroup id   ind
9    lightred  1   red
3        cyan  2  blue
10     marine  2  blue
12       rose  3   red
1    bordeaux  4   red
4     darkred  4   red
13        sky  4  blue
2      bottle  5 green
6        gras  5 green
7  lightgreen  5 green
5     darkred  6   red
8  lightgreen  6 green
11     marine  6  blue
```

You can do:

```
colors=unlist(list(red=red,blue=blue,green=green))
names(colors)=sub("\\d+","",names(colors))
data$color=names(colors[match(subgroup,colors)])
data
  id   subgroup color
1   1   lightred   red
2   2     marine  blue
3   2       cyan  blue
4   3       rose   red
5   4   bordeaux   red
6   4    darkred   red
7   4        sky  blue
8   5       gras green
9   5     bottle green
10  5 lightgreen green
11  6    darkred   red
12  6     marine  blue
13  6 lightgreen green
```